# How to use MongoDB with Sequence class or generator from Keras?

Tags: python, mongodb, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm going to store about 500K images in MongoDB and use this dataset to train a neural network with Keras.

I've chosen database instead of separate images on disk to improve the data loading speed. Loading separate images for training has took about 1.5 hours - too much.

Total data volume is about 1 Tb, it definitely does not fit in RAM, therefore the way to go is using method `fit_generator` of the model class or use [`keras.utils.Sequence`](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence).

I'd like to stick to the `Sequence`. As the docs say,

> The use of keras.utils.Sequence guarantees the ordering and guarantees the single use of every input per epoch when using use_multiprocessing=True.

Subclassing of the `Sequence` (as well as writing a generator), wrapping database connection, requires implementing `__len__` and `__get_item__`.

There are no problems with `__len__` but `__get_item__` confuses me, because it is me, the author, who is responsible for guarantee of ordering and single use.

The main confusion is in object numbering in the MongoDB.

The method `__get_item__` of the `Sequence` subclass must return complete batch, and it must return the same batch repeatedly given the same input index.

The database assigns unique identifiers (`_id` or `ObjectID` in pymongo) to the documents in the collection, and I would like to use them for collecting images in batches, but cannot figure out, how to do it.

The arithmetics `(max_object_id - min_object_id) / n_per_batch` is impossible since the method of `ObjectID` creation makes no sense in subtracting them.

I would like to get advices on what is the best method to split `_ids` into non-overlapping intervals and enumerate these intervals.

I've got an old solution of similar problem for LMDB, borrowed from somewhere on Github, that creates additional pickle file, storing array of keys. I don't like it for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experiments have shown that simple solution works well. I just retrieve list of ObjectIDs in `__init__` using `projection={'_id': True}`, then retrieve respective documents.

The code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879750/using-keras-utils-sequence-multiprocessing-and-data-base-when-to-connect).